# Смена значения XML из кода фрагмента

Tags: java, android-studio

В color.xml я имею вот эту строку

```
<color name="CustomBack">#5589fa</color>
```

как мне из "Фрагмента" Function.java поменять значение "#5589fa"
допустим на то которое будет указано в EditText.

Comment: значения xml-аттрибутов "зашиваются"на этапе компиляции и изменить их потом нельзя.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Значения параметров, таких как цвета, строки и т.п. захардкожены и изменять их если и можно, то не принято. Задайте в colors.xml цвета, которые вы будете использовать в вашем приложении. А затем изменяйте цвета у тех элементов, у которых вам нужно, путем обращения к заданным цветам в xml разметке.
Например у вас есть какой-то TextView с id my_text_view. В активити создаете поле для этого элемента. И меняете ему цвет на любой цвет из colors.xml

```
TextView myView = findViewById(R.id.my_text_view);
myView.setTextColor(R.color.CustomBack);
```

Если вам нужно обращаться к этим полям из фрагмента, то во фрагменте получайте экземпляр активности и действуйте через него.

```
View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.forecast_fragment, container, false);
TextView myView = root.findViewById(R.id.my_text_view);
myView.setTextColor(R.color.CustomBack);
```